# Accessing and modifying vertex color in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

so I am pretty new to geometry nodes and I´m kinda stuck.

I have a mesh with vertex colors (stored in the `Col` attribute) and I´ve used geometry nodes to add a bunch of cylinders on there, setting their colors using the `Col` data.
Now I´d like to sort them into a grid depending on their colors. Basically removing them from their original position on the mesh by transforming their RGB to XYZ values.

Here´s my current setup:
[image]

And here´s a very rough sketch of what i want it to look like:
[image]

Now I´ve tried a bunch of things like capturing the attributes but it doesn´t work.
How do I access the `Col` values I can see in the Spreadsheet?
Is it even possible to do what I´m trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

Via the Input (defined as Vector in the group input) and entering "Col" in the modifier you can access the vertex color.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for `Named Attribute` node, it was added in Blender 3.2. Screenshot is from Blender 3.3 alpha.

[image: Named Attribute node]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!